# Sql find records in join table which match filter exactly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Best to explain with an example :)

Let's say I have a the tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ShoppingBasket (
    ShoppingBasketId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY dbo.Customer(CustomerId),
    ItemName NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

Example data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer
VALUES (1, 'Steve'), (2, 'Bucky')

INSERT INTO dbo.ShoppingBasket 
VALUES (1, 1, 'Banana'), (2, 1, 'Orange'), (3, 2, 'Orange')
```

Now, I want to find all customers, that have a Banana and an Orange in their shopping basket exactly. So in the case above, it should return Steve only. Since Bucky has only a Banana.

The following query works for this

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer AS c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ShoppingBasket AS b
    WHERE b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
       AND b.ItemName IN ('Banana', 'Orange')
    GROUP BY CustomerId
    HAVING COUNT(CustomerId) = 2
)
```

That's fine. Now, if I want all customers that only have an Orange, the above query fails since

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer AS c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ShoppingBasket AS b
    WHERE b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
       AND b.ItemName = 'Orange'
    GROUP BY CustomerId
    HAVING COUNT(CustomerId) = 1
)
```

is filtering out the shopping basket and then applying the group and having clause. Thus both Steve and Bucky are return whereas only Bucky should be returned.

Could someone point me in the right direction to find such a query, I suppose I can always do another `NOT EXIST` inside the exist subquery, to make sure no other items are found. E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer AS c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ShoppingBasket AS b
    WHERE b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
       AND b.ItemName = 'Orange'
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM dbo.ShoppingBasket AS b2
           WHERE b2.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
              AND b.ItemName <> 'Orange'
       )
)
```

But was wandering if there's a more elegant way to handle it. One that preferably doesn't do an extra, negated join on the same table.

Comment: With that design everyone only has one shopping basket.

Comment: I've made a correction on your statement _"Since Bucky has only a Banana."_. . . Bucky actually only has an _'Orange'_ by your example of `INSERT INTO dbo.ShoppingBasket VALUES . . . (3, 2, 'Orange')`. Bucky is CustomerID = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the distinct ItemName instead of the customerId eg:

```
  select c.*
  from dbo.Customer
  inner join(
    select CustomerId, count(distinct ItemName) count_name
    from ShoppingBasket
    where ItemName IN ('Banana', 'Orange')
    group by CustomerId
    having count_name = 2
  )  t on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

If you need  a twice check on number of item name an type you could compose the inner join in two part

```
select c.*
from dbo.Customer
inner join(
  select CustomerId
  from ShoppingBasket b
  where ItemName IN ('Banana', 'Orange')
  INNER JOIN (
  Select CustomerId, count(distinct ItemName) count_name
  from ShoppingBasket
  group by CustomerId
  having count_name = 2
  ) t2 ON t2.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
)  t on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

and for Orange ..

```
select c.*
from dbo.Customer
inner join(
  select CustomerId
  from ShoppingBasket b
  where ItemName IN ('Orange')
  INNER JOIN (
  Select CustomerId, count(distinct ItemName) count_name
  from ShoppingBasket
  group by CustomerId
  having count_name = 1
  ) t2 ON t2.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
)  t on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

The problem is that the in clause in ambiguos  because return true also for ShoppingBasket CustomerId with One positive check 
then instead of an in clause ( equivalent to OR ) you should work on and clause for all the customer that have a number of distinct name equivalent  at then number you are looking for

```
  Select CustomerId
  from ShoppingBasket a
  inner join ShoppingBasket b a.ItemName = 'Orange' and b.ItemName = 'Banana'
  and customerId IN (
      Select CustomerId 
      from ShoppingBasket
      group by CustomerId
      having count(distinct ItemName) = 2
  )
```

Comment: Ok, but what about the case when I searching for only an Orange? Even in this case both customers are returned. Whereas only Bucky should be returned

Comment: Yep that's what I suspected. Will need to join and count separately. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Umair  . well . then if my answer is useful or right  .. the best thanks  is a proper rating  ..

Comment: Sorry, the reason I haven't accepted is because there is another case: Shopping basket has 1 has ('Orange', 'Banana'), 2 has ('Orange', 'Apple'). If I want all that only have ('Orange', 'Banana'), query above still returns both. Because `In` will match Orange and both have count 2.

I think the solution is check the negative... Am investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this with `group by` and `having`.  If you want both "banana" and "orange":

```
select sb.customerId
from dbo.ShoppingBasket sb
where sb.itemName in ('banana', 'orange')
group by sb.customerId
having count(distinct itemName) = 2;  -- has both
```

If you want the two items and nothing else, then use this more general form:

```
select sb.customerId
from dbo.ShoppingBasket sb
where sb.itemName in ('banana', 'orange')
group by sb.customerId
having sum(case when sb.itemName = 'banana' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when sb.itemName = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when sb.itemName not in ('orange, 'banana') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

You can extend this version easily.  Each item gets its own `sum()`.  You can also include multiple items to support, say, "banana and (orange or clementine)".